# Cellular Automata algorithm doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, automata

I'm currently working on an electronics simulation software (something really basic) using Python and libTCOD (just to "render" the board).
So, I've got a 78x47 2D list which stores the board information (cell type, id, state, coords...) and a simple algorithm to simulate wires (wireworld).
Everything seems to be going fine, except for one thing: The "electrons" only move towards the left side of the wires. So I thought it may be something related to the way it runs the algorithm.

WireWorld wires have three possible states: Conductor, tail or head.

- Head: State "2", changes to Tail in the next step
- Tail: State "1", changes to Conductor in the next step
- Conductor: State "0", is the default state, changes to Head if there are any Heads at a 1 cell range

Here's how the simulation should go (H for head, t for tail, - for wire):

- Step 1: ----H----
- Step 2: ---HtH---
- Step 3: --Ht-tH--
- Step 4: -Ht---tH-
- Step 5: Ht-----tH
- Step 6: t-------t
- Step 7: ---------

But this is what currently happens:

- Step 1: ----H----
- Step 2: ---Ht----
- Step 3: --Ht-----
- Step 4: -Ht------
- Step 5: Ht-------
- Step 6: t--------
- Step 7: ---------

See? The electron head only moves towards the left side of the wires.

That's my current algorithm code:

```
def run(self):
    for DX, DY in ((-1,-1), (-1,+0), (-1,+1), (+0,-1), (+0,+1), (+1,-1), (+1,+0), (+1,+1)):
        if BOARD[self.Y+DY][self.X+DX].STATE == 2 and self.STATE == 0:
            self.STATE = 2
            return True

        if self.STATE == 2:
            self.STATE = 1
        elif self.STATE == 1:
            self.STATE = 0
```

And that's how I run the simulation steps:

```
for y in range(BOARD_HEIGHT):
    for x in range(BOARD_WIDTH):
        BOARD[y][x].run()
```

Do I need to simulate each cell in an independent thread?

Comment: 1. is this for logic/digital circuits or for analog circuits? 2. I am confused with the state values why you have different meaning for head and tail? for digital circuits the wire side is input or output  at a time so why not encode that and add info about state L/H/Z (low,high,hi impedance). then you know you have to propagate from output to input direction only. Also a list of interconnections per each component;s pin is a better way. With analog circuits you need to store potential information of each side and compute the currents... and or combine with current flow simulations ...

Comment: It's more of a simple turing-complete environment/sandbox.

Comment: So you mean Sequence Combinatorial Logic (Turing automata is Tape based computer concept) In that case handle it as digital circuit.. Each I/O pin has its state and interconnection list. so take each Gate;s inputs generate output pins states and then propagate output pin states to each input connected to it from interconnections list.

Comment: You `run` method can set at most one "wire" to "head" per iteration. I would suggest that you use two `BOARD`s (btw, no self here? global variable?) and don't `return` after the first change.

Comment: No "self" because there are different types of "cells", each with their own states, properties and "run" functions. Each "cell" type is a class, it's not the entire program that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for multithreading, you just have to make sure that more than one '- -> H'-transitions are possible in each simulation step.

I've coded a minimal example starting from your code (but with slightly different class layout):

```
class Simul(object):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        board_1 = [[None for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]
        board_2 = [[None for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]
        self.boards = [board_1, board_2]
        self.current = 0
        self.pretty = {None: ' ', 0: '-', 1: 't', 2: 'H'}
        self.w = width
        self.h = height

    def print_board(self):
        for row in self.boards[self.current]:
            for cell in row:
                print(self.pretty[cell], end='')
            print()

    def run(self):
        BOARD = self.boards[self.current]
        other_board = self.boards[- self.current + 1]
        for row in range(self.h):
            for col in range(self.w):
                cur_cell = BOARD[row][col]
                set_h = False
                for DX, DY in ((-1,-1), (-1,+0), (-1,+1), (+0,-1), (+0,+1),  (+1,-1), (+1,+0), (+1,+1)):
                    try:
                        if BOARD[row+DY][col+DX] == 2 and cur_cell == 0:
                            other_board[row][col] = 2
                            set_h = True
                            break
                    except IndexError:
                        pass

                if set_h:
                    continue

                if cur_cell == 2:
                    other_board[row][col] = 1
                elif cur_cell == 1:
                    other_board[row][col] = 0
                elif cur_cell == 0:
                    other_board[row][col] = 0
        self.current = - self.current + 1




if __name__ == '__main__':
    simul = Simul(10, 5)
    for col in range(10):
        simul.boards[0][3][col] = 0
    for row in range(3):
        simul.boards[0][row][4] = 0
    simul.boards[0][3][4] = 2
    simul.print_board()
    simul.run()
    simul.print_board()
```

Output:

```
    -     
    -     
    -     
----H-----

    -     
    -     
    H     
---HtH----
```